# Is $1＋p/2!＋p^2/3!＋p^3/4!・・・$ convergent in $ \Bbb{Z}_p$?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

Let $p$ be an odd prime.Is $1＋p/2!＋p^2/3!＋p^3/4!・・・$ convergent in $ \Bbb{Z}_p$?
I know $1＋p＋p^2/2!＋p^3/3!＋・・・$ converges but what about the titled case ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_exponential_function

Comment: Titled question is not p adic exp.

Comment: In $\Bbb Z_p$, a sequence $(a_n)_1^{\infty}$ converges iff $|a_n - a_{n+1}|_p \to 0 [n \to +\infty]$.

Comment: @xbh, actually, the wacky ultrametric property of the $p$-adics entails that an infinite sum $\sum_n a_n$ in $\mathbb Q_p$ (and similar) converges if and only if $|a_n|_p\to 0$. The crazy converse to Cauchy's theorem that, in $\mathbb R$, if an infinite sum does converge, its summands go to $0$. :)

Comment: @buoyant It's a field. Can you see why that's sufficient to derive the title problem from the exponential?

Comment: Your function in the title equals to $(\mathrm{exp}_{p}(x) - 1) / p$, so it has the same convergence radius as $p$-adic exponential $\mathrm{exp}_{p}$.

Comment: @Seewoo Lee In Zp, p is not invertible.